# Blazor 8 Server-Side QuickGrid default CSS not loading

Tags: css, blazor-server-side

Blazor 8 Server-Side app with a QuickGrid minimal configuration.
I am trying to make the grid displayed as in default example however looks like grid loads correctly but styles are not applyed.

I am using these two packages only:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.EntityFrameworkAdapter" Version="8.0.0" />
```

and a grid located in a component is defined as below:

```
<div class="grid">
    <QuickGrid Items="@FilteredItems"  Class="table table-striped" Pagination="_pagination">
        <PropertyColumn Title="Imie" Property="@(c => c.Name)" Sortable="true" Class="btn btn-link">
            <ColumnOptions>
                <div class="search-box">
                    <input type="search" autofocus @bind="nameFilter" @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="Country name..." />
                </div>
            </ColumnOptions>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Title="Nazwisko" Property="@(c => c.Surname)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Right" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.Email)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Right" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.Street)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Right" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.PostalCode)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Right" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.City)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Right" /> 
    </QuickGrid>
</div>
```

and the output is:
[image]

App.razor has a css link to

```
<link href="ProjectName.styles.css" onactivaterel="stylesheet" />
```

file contains import:
[image: import scp.css]

Any ideas why CSS are not being loaded properly? none of default quickgrid css classes are present

Comment: Try to force a reload using the shift key.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same issue and tried to ask the community in [GitHub Here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53504) and waiting for the answer.

For now I've solved my problem this way :
Add this link to the **<head>** of **Layout.razor** or **App.razor**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.bundle.scp.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

And If you are using a Blazor component in a **RazorPage** or **MVC WebApp** Also add this line

```
<base href="~/" />
```

to the **<head>** of **Layout.razor**

---

**UPDATE**

In addition of **site.css** or **app.css**, every fresh Dotnet webApp has a

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}.styles.css

In the **<head>** of the **layout.cshtml** (for RazorPage and MVC webApps) or in the **App.Razor** (for Blazor webApps), I had deleted that before, but after adding this line again, the QuickGrid Css has been loaded well.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/{YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

For Blazor Web Apps use this in the **<head>** of **App.Razor**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}.styles.css" />
```

You can read more about ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation [Here in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

!!! IMPORTANT !!!
NEVER DELETE THIS :

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}.styles.css

It should remains in your project to render components styles