# Blazor QuickGrid CSS not loading

Tags: blazor, quickgrid

I've upgrade an existing project from core 3.1 to core 8.  I'd like to use QuickGrid to replace an existing top level of a multiple nest set of HTML tables.  Everything seems to work except none of the formatting from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.bundle.scp.css is showing up.  Example the Paginator  goes down the page starting with Item Count, then 2 tiny boxes instead of the left arrows, then page of, and finally 2 more tiny boxes instead of the right arrows.  Reviewing the HTML in the browser it is referencing BootStrap's _Print.scss instead of the QuickGrid css.  Yet, it all works.  The using statements are on both the razor and cs files of the form for Quick Grid component, and I just installed the latest QuickGrid from NuGet for Core 8; so not sure what I might be missing.
[image: Paginator missing CSS]

I did get it to display properly by downloading and including the file Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.bundle.scp.css as part of the applications css files, and adding the link in the head tag of the _Host file; however, I'd prefer to pull directly from package especially for future upgrades.
[image: Using Local Copy of CSS]

Comment: same issue, also investigating.

Comment: same here, seem a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523248/blazor-8-server-side-quickgrid-default-css-not-loading

Comment: My problem solved and I've wrote an ansewer here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523248

Answer (score 2):

Control+F5 did the trick for me...